# Как вызвать элемент через атрибут фреймворка?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, uikit

Юзаю UIkit, там есть модалка но вызывается она через непонятный мне uk-toggle и с модалкой собственно связывается тегом uk-modal. Я пытаюсь вызвать эту самую модалку через 5 сек после загрузки сайта, но никак. Даже если с обычной ссылки убрать uk-toggle - вызов модалки не сработает... Подскажете как решить? Может как-то с атрибутом вызвать, возможно ли? Пример - https://jsfiddle.net/sr9eg2xe/

```
<a href="#modal-example" uk-toggle>Open</a>
<div id="modal-example" class="uk-flex-top" uk-modal>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body uk-margin-auto-vertical">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае элементы связываются при помощи атрибута `id`, а атрибуты `uk-toggle` и `uk-modal` привязывают обработчики фреймворка к элементам.

Если посмотреть на классы модалки в открытом состоянии, то у нее будут 
присутствовать классы `uk-modal uk-flex uk-open`.

В коде:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('modal-example');
setTimeout(function(){
    modal.__uikit__.modal.show()
}, 5000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sr9eg2xe/5/

Comment: В точку, это то что мне и нужно было. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: А можешь еще подсказать как в этот код всунуть анимацию которая при появлении окна?

Comment: лучше вместо добавления классов дергать метод фреймворка, вот так: `modal.__uikit__.modal.show()`.
тогда и анимация будет

Comment: Мм неплохо, спасибо еще раз. Мне на будущее пригодиться